# can't enable scroll bar on css style overflow: scroll on <canva>s or container div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, scrollbar

I am trying to make a long drawing canvas, but users can exit drawing mode and go to Hand scroll mode just like you normally scroll website on your phone.

I was thinking to add a scrollbar on the side of the canvas. But it would be better if we can scroll the canvas normally like we reading a website on phone.

html,css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />

  <style>
    .container {
      margin: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
      }
    #main {border: 1px solid #0000ff; overflow: scroll;}
  </style>
  
  <script src="draw.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <button id="clear">clear button that will clear teh canvas</button><br>
  <canvas id="main" width="250" height="1000"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code for touch drawing:

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
  
    var canvas  = document.querySelector('#main');
    // const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    // const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var canvastop = canvas.offsetTop;
  
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
    var lastx;
    var lasty;
  
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.lineWidth = 5;
  
    function clear() {
      context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
      context.rect(0, 0, 300, 300);
      context.fill();
    }
  
    function dot(x,y) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.fillStyle = "#000000";
      context.arc(x,y,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
    }
  
    function line(fromx,fromy, tox,toy) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
      context.lineTo(tox, toy);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
    }
  
    canvas.ontouchstart = function(event){                   
      event.preventDefault();                 
      
      lastx = event.touches[0].clientX;
      lasty = event.touches[0].clientY - canvastop;
  
      dot(lastx,lasty);
    }
  
    canvas.ontouchmove = function(event){                   
      event.preventDefault();                 
  
      var newx = event.touches[0].clientX;
      var newy = event.touches[0].clientY - canvastop;
  
      line(lastx,lasty, newx,newy);
      
      lastx = newx;
      lasty = newy;
    }
  
  
    var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear')
    clearButton.onclick = clear
  
    clear()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you'd like to do. However no need to add 'scroll' to everything.

Try this:

```
.container {
    margin: 10px;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    width: 250px;
    height:600px;
    overflow-y: auto
}
```

And then:

```
<canvas id="main"></canvas>
```

In this way your canvas will get a vertical scroll only if its contents is more than 600px, and at the same time you'll be able to scroll the page in a normal way.

Comment: Hey sorry, I had tried to add the "overflow-y: auto: and it worked. But I wonder if there is another way that I can scroll even that we touch the canvas. So we will disbale the drawing on  canvas and have a normal scroll function